# Identify whether message body has sequenced with image

Tags: gmail-api

This is the result of message part body after converted into string

```
Hi,

[image: Inline image 1]

[image: Inline image 2]


[image: Inline image 1]
```

first three lines are typed text and last one is auto generated text coming from gmail api...

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to check whether there is an image in the message body. Is that correct?

Comment: yes its right, but if the message body already have same text like auto generated text from gmail api. How i suppose to identify which one is auto generated text from gmail api.